# I've gone to or been to a gym regularly

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, been-vs-gone

I started to go to a gym regularly in May. Now I continue this habit.

What should I say to express this idea?

> I've been to a gym regularly since  May.

or

> I've gone to a gym regularly since May.

What do you think? Why?

I think "been to" is correct, because "gone to" means you haven't returned.

"Been to a gym regularly" refers to go and come back, go and come back, go and come back.

Comment: Either works. You can't go somewhere twice unless you left,  so "gone to" cannot mean no return in this context.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to express the idea that it is an ongoing current habitual action, then you can use the Present Simple instead. If you want to include the time from which the habit started, use the Present Perfect Continuous. For example:

- I go to the gym (= I go regularly)
- I've been going to the gym since May (= I go regularly and this habit started in May)

Comment: In the U.S., neither of the options in the original post is particularly idiomatic. Most of the time, an American would use "I've been going to a gym (regularly since May)" to express the point, as suggested in this answer. "I've gone to a gym regularly since May" is acceptable/understandable but, imo, unnatural. "I've been to a gym regularly since May" sounds even stranger to me. Also, for what it's worth, we'd usually say "the gym" rather than "a gym."